# How to add sliding tabs on an existing navigation bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a navigation drawer on my current application. However, it seems like I'm having more modules coming in, I have to make sure that my application is still organized. So I was thinking to add a sliding tab on one of my navigation drawer fragment.

During my attempt, something went wrong and the log shows the following error

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
```

I tried googling for the issue with no success in getting the solution. Can anyone tell me what is actually wrong with my code?

My following files are.

`MainActivity.java`

```java
package com.epsilon.rfcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private MyFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = {"Free Space Propagation Model", "Two Ray Ground Propagation Model", "Power Conversion", "Wavelength Conversion", "Link Budget"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                displayView(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Intent intent = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyFragment();
                break;
                //intent = new Intent(this, FreeSpaceActivity.class);
                //break;

            case 1:
                intent = new Intent(this, TransmissionActivity.class);
                break;

            case 2:
                intent = new Intent(this, PowerActivity.class);
                break;

            case 3:
                intent = new Intent(this, WavelengthActivity.class);
                break;

            case 4:
                intent = new Intent(this, LinkBudgetActivity.class);
                break;

            //case 5: intent = new Intent(this,MapActivity.class);break;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`MyFragment.java` //This is a new java file added corresponding to my attempt to add the sliding tab.

```java
package com.epsilon.rfcalculator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    public MyFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        super.onCreate(instance);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);
        // Here we load the content for each tab.
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("One"), FreeSpaceActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Two"), TransmissionActivity.class, null);
        return v;
    }
    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;
            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }
        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
        {
            private final Context mContext;
            public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
            {
                mContext = context;
            }
            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }
        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }
        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
        {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Holy Operating Systems, Batdroid!"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```